# How does value binding work in [ngModel]?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I would use the following code if I wanted only one checkbox to be selected in a given list of check-boxes:

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let account of accounts; let i = index" text-wrap>
        <ion-label> 
            <div user-name>{{account.firstName}}</div>
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox item-right secondary  [ngModel]= "checkedIdx== i"
             (ngModelChange)="modelStateChanged($event, user, i)"></ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The following is the TypeScript code:

```ts
 checkedIdx:number = -1;
 modelStateChanged(event, user, index) {
   this.checkedIdx = index;
 }
```

Although the above code is working, I don't understand the 6th line. I read [this blog](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) but it is still not clear how the above solution works.

What is bound to the `[ngModel]` in the above code (an expression or Boolean value) and how does the 6th line of code work?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
[ngModel]= "checkedIdx== i"
```

sets the `checked` property to `true` when `checkedIdx` equals `i`

This line

```
(ngModelChange)="modelStateChanged($event, user, i)"
```

calls `modelStateChanged(...)` when the inputs `checked` property changes and passes the current `checked` value, the `user` value and the current iteration index from `*ngFor`.

The short form would be

```
[(ngModel)]="checkedValues[i]"
```

but with more complex logic like in your example it needs to be split in `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`

`NgModel` is a directive used for binding values to form elements and `ngModelChange` is an event emitted by `NgModel` when the value of the input changes.

Comment: but when one check box is already selected and user is selecting another checkbox, the two check-boxes states are changing then why modelStateChanged() is called only once and how previous checkbox is being deseleted in this case?.

Comment: When `checkedIdx` is updated then `checkedIdx == i` is `false` for this checkbox and becomes `true` for another checkbox. Angular change detection runs frequently (when an event happened) and updates (re-evaluates) all these bindings.

Comment: and when we are selecting/deselecting a particular checkbox, this.checkedIdx value remains same so then what is [ngModel]= "checkedIdx== i" doing in this case?

Comment: If `this.checkedIdx` stays the same then change detection will probably add the same value (`true`) again. (There can be subtle timing issues, especially with booleans where Angular doesn't recognize changes properly when a value changes from `true` to `false` and back to `true` while Angular didn't get a chance to run change detection in between.)

Comment: but checkbox is correctly toggling its state and this is the source of confusion and when I'm using (ngChange) then it is following the behavior you are talking about(i.e ngChange is called multiple times.) but then it is not possible to get the behavior I want.

Comment: `ngModel` probably just doesn't update it back after you click it. This would be easier with a Plunker example where I can investigate the actual behavior you're describing.